# How to publish an XML file to Maven repo from Gradle

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I have a static xml file that I want to publish to a Maven repository (my local Maven repo for now) from Gradle using the maven-publish plugin.

build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group 'com.example.gradletest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

publishing {
    publications {
        beta(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'feature-file'
            artifact 'src/main/resources/features.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but I would like to add a classifier too, where should I define that?
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html says in section 68.2.2 that it should be possible to do:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        beta(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'feature-file'
            artifact ('src/main/resources/features.xml') {
                classifier 'features'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but then I get this error:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'testapplication'.

> Exception thrown while executing model rule: org.gradle.api.publish.plugins.PublishingPlugin$Rules#publishing(org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionContainer)
>   No signature of method: java.io.File.call() is applicable for argument types: (build_101arjzoe908rdkh5aikrn6bt$_run_closure5_closure16_closure19_closure20) values: [build_101arjzoe908rdkh5aikrn6bt$_run_closure5_closure16_closure19_closure20@2aa7399c]
>   Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), list()

Using the below solution will correctly add the classifier, but will also change the packaging in the pom.xml from `<packaging>xml</packaging>` to `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. I don't want that.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        beta(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'feature-file'
            artifact source: 'src/main/resources/features.xml', classifier: 'features'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the map syntax as specified [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html#org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication:artifact(java.lang.Object)).

```groovy
publishing {
    publications {
        beta(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'feature-file'
            artifact source: 'src/main/resources/features.xml', classifier: 'features'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that adds the classifier, but it also changes the packaging from xml to pom. I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `pom { packaging 'xml' }`

works for me (gradle 3.2.1)

`publishing {
    publications {
        beta(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'feature-file'
            artifact source: 'src/main/resources/features.xml', classifier: 'features'
            pom { packaging 'xml' }
        }
    }
}`